# Software for Palm HotSync on OS X (not The Missing Sync)

Tags: gratis, osx, synchronization

I’m looking for a piece of software (open-source would be nice) to sync my Palm Zire (yes, one of THOSE) to my Macbook running OS X 10.10 Yosemite (soon to be 10.11 El Capitan). I don’t want to have to pay for Missing Sync, since this is only for reminiscing.

I’d like at least the following features:

- Application installs
- Backups
- Copying of Memo Pad notes

Although more would be nice.

Comment: I've been using Missing Sync for several years now. Just upgraded the OS to 10.11 (El Capitan) and it now fails to load. Went to the web site and the software is discontinued. So even if you were willing to pay some money, we're out of luck on that front. I'll report back here if I find a replacement. I still use my Tungsten T3 daily.

Comment: Windows XP in VirtualBox?